# how to insert array data in single column in mysql using codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to insert array data into database using codeigniter. when I print that values using `print_r()` fun.

It shows correct result, but when I click on save button it inserts blank values in table.

I just want to store multiple medicine names in prescription table for particular prescription_id i am trying to insert data using insert_batch function but it saves blank records

this is my model code:

```
public function add_prescription($data) {

    $data['medicine_name'] = $data['medicine_nm[]'];
    print_r($data['medicine_name']);

    $this->db->insert_batch('pre',$data);
     return $this->db->insert_id($pre_id);
  }
```

controller code--

```
public function prescription($patient_id = NULL, $app_date = NULL, $hour = NULL , $min = NULL) {

    //Check if user has logged in 
    if (!$this->session->userdata('user_name') || $this->session->userdata('user_name') == '') {
        redirect('login/index/');

    } else {

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
          $data['medicine_nm[]']=$this->input->post('medicine_nm[]');   
           $this->patient_model->add_prescription($data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show us  your code. what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Hey where is ur insert_batch function ??

Comment: Proof read your question before submit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `json_encode` that array and then insert it into the database like

```
$data = json_encode($array);

$this->db->insert('column_name',$data);
```

And while fetching you need to `decode` it

```
$data = json_decode($column_result);
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: You need to tell us if it didn't worked & what error you are getting

Comment: it gives blank view page and database column is empty

Comment: We are not returning to view page here so you need to handle it by passing insert id if you want but debug your issue tell me what it gives you in $data,if you `print_r($data);` just above model call in controller

Comment: Also can you tell what is `$pre_id` in your model code

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public function add_prescription($name) {


$data = array(
 'medicine_name' => $name
  );

  $query = $this->db->insert('table_name',$data);

  return $query->result_array();
 }
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: you can't save the array in database directly, you need to data `encode` to `json` format.

Comment: well i am using codeigniter as my framework for about a year, and this works fine for me! i am not using that encode to json format thing, i am just using what is in the manual

Comment: Yes, I tried that also, it generates 500 error. @ GGsThePlayDude

Comment: public function prescription($patient_id = NULL, $app_date = NULL, $hour = NULL , $min = NULL) { //Check if user has logged in if (!$this->session->userdata('user_name') || $this->session->userdata('user_name') == '') { redirect('login/index/'); } else {

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE) {
         $data['medicine_nm[]']=$this->input->post('medicine_nm[]');    
        $this->patient_model->add_prescription($data);
        }
    }

Comment: when i use your code print_r will give this output:-     Array ( [medicine_name] => Array ( [0] => sss [1] => vvv ) )  But records not inserted in table  @ GGsThePlayDude

Comment: r u trying to insert array inside single column

Comment: @GGsThePlayDude i want to insert values from 3 fields into a single column in database, can you help me with that?